# Добавление переменной в QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно постом отправить переменную.

Пробовал так:

```
QByteArray data = "text=";
data.append(ui->lineEdit->text());

manager->post(request, data);
```

Ошибка: "no matching member function for call to 'append'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37802575/6944845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QByteArray` это последовательность байт, а `QString` (ui->lineEdit->text()) - строка. Соответственно вы должны преобразовать строку в последовательность байт - будет это UTF-8, Windows-1251 или еще что-то.

Т.е. [toLocal8Bit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit)

```
data.append(ui->lineEdit->text().toLocal8Bit());
```

или [toUtf8](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toUtf8)

```
 data.append(ui->lineEdit->text().toUtf8());
```